# Error during deserialization of json when jsonTextReader.LinePosition > 1000

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following code to deserilize JSON objects sent over a stream.

When running this code with network stream, I get an error message every time the `jsonTextReader.LinePosition` crosses the value `1000`. Even if it's the same object that has been previously successfully deserialized. i.e. all the JSON messages being sent are correctly formatted and match the Schema.

And when using a `MemoryStream`, weirdly, this code works perfectly irrespective of the `jsonTextReader.LinePosition`.

Has anyone else experienced similar issue when the `LinePosition` goes beyond `1000`?

```
var Serializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, new UTF8Encoding());
var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader)
{
    CloseInput = false,
    SupportMultipleContent = true
};

while (true)
{
    if (jsonTextReader.Read())
    {
        message = Serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

**PS** I can't move the `if (jsonTextReader.Read())` to the `while` loop because it's done in a library function. In short, I can't change the flow of code.

---

#### Update

@[Tewr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61991/tewr) suggested that it could be `maxlength` some value restricted to 1000/1024 on the source stream. But when I run the following, it works fine.

```
while (true)
{
    if (jsonTextReader.Read())
    {
        message = Serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonTextReader);
    }
    else
    {
        jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I can't do this because as mentioned, part of the code is run in a library. And this doesn't entirely resolve the problem (what if there is a single JSON object string longer than 1024?).

Now, when creating a new `JsonTextReader`, everything is reset. Including `jsonTextReader.LinePosition`. So, not letting `jsonTextReader.LinePosition` hitting `1000` makes things work. In that case, what is the relation between `jsonTextReader.LinePosition` and `NetworkStream`/`Socket`?

---

Here are some of the error message I get:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: T. Path 'timeStamp', line 1, position 1026.

for

> {"version":"35","timestamp":"2018-05-14T07:52:23.3347793Z","message":{"type":"msgType","value":{"id":"44","params":["AA","AC","BD"]}}}

and

> Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: ". Path 'message.indicator', line 1, position 1023.

for

> {"version":"35","timestamp":"2018-05-14T07:52:23.3347793Z","message":{"type":"msgType","value":{"id":"44","params":["AA","AC","BD"]},"indicator":{"data":"normal","indication":"no"}}}

---

Testing with `MemoryStream`:

```
var str = "{\"version\":\"35\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-05-14T07:52:23.3347793Z\",\"message\":{\"type\":\"msgType\",\"value\":{\"id\":\"44\",\"params\":[\"AA\",\"AC\",\"BD\"]},\"indicator\":{\"data\":\"normal\",\"indication\":\"no\"}}}";

str += str;
str += str;
str += str;

var ms = new MemoryStream();

ms.Write(str.GetBytes(), 0, str.GetBytes().Count());
ms.Position = 0;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("StringLength:{0}", str.Length));

var streamReader = new StreamReader(ms);
var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader)
{
    CloseInput = false,
    SupportMultipleContent = true
};
```

and then use the `jsonTextReader` as before.

Comment: It's not really clear in your question how you tested with MemoryStream (*how* did you get any data into it?), so I'll ask explicitly: Did you try dumping the full network stream to a MemoryStream before serialization ?

Comment: @Tewr Updated the question with code used to test with `MemoryStream`

Comment: Just an outside observation - all the info you posted suggests that this is not a serialization issue, but the source network stream is somehow truncated. Any way for you to outrule that? The number 1000 (1024?) sounds suspiciously like a configured maxlength of something, somewhere. Maybe you should focus on verifying the source stream rather than the json?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Will look into it.

Comment: @Tewr Looked into it, didn't find anything that is limited to 1000 or 1024 on the source stream side. Updated the question.

Comment: Not related to the error, but you're not disposing resources that implement IDisposable. See `using` keyword.

Comment: This seems hairy, but I'm a bit intrigued. If I were you, i'd build a [mcve]. Sometimes just by building that, you find the solution to the problem.